# Using AS3 to apply color to dynamically created spark rectangles

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

in FlashBuilder I want to dynamically generate approximately 1200 rectangles from a CSV file (these are all different colours) which will perform an action on Click.

What is the best way to go about doing this? I've read that the drawing API on Air and Android is not a good idea, and am thinking about using the Spark Rectangle class, but I can't seem to work out how to apply a colour to it if I'm generating them dynamically using AS?

Comment: You should specify what format of your data (in csv you have points, or shape's sizes ). Also, show some code. It seems to me that the Rectangle class you are using is a data structure, and not a shape/graphic related class. Look into Sprite's graphics property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After reading in your CSV, loop through the elements and call a function something like so:

```
        private function addRect(color:uint, xPos:Number, yPos:Number, width:Number, height:Number):void {
            var rect:Rect = new Rect();
            rect.x = xPos;
            rect.y = yPos;
            rect.width = width;
            rect.height = height;
            var fillColor:SolidColor = new SolidColor(color);
            rect.fill = fillColor;
            var obj:Group = new Group();
            obj.addElement(rect);
            obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.onClick);
            this.addElement(obj);
        }

        private function onClick(e:Event):void {
            trace("clicked");
        }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This answer is the nearest to what I'm looking for, however, how would you then access the child under which the container was clicked? As I now have a list of rectangles which each need to return individual data? 

I tried to move the eventlistener into the individual rectangles but had no joy!

Answer (score 2):

You can do the entire UI declaratively.  Parse the CSV into data structures, and pop it into an `ArrayCollection`.  In this example, I just threw together three samples.

Then, create a `DataGroup` and set the `dataProvider="rectangles"` and then create an `itemRenderer`.

This example works well, IMO:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            var rectangles:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {color: 0x00FF00, x: 5, y: 10, width: 30, height: 40},
                {color: 0xFF0000, x: 50, y: 100, width: 300, height: 400},
                {color: 0x0000FF, x: 55, y: 10, width: 30, height: 40},
                ]);

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:DataGroup dataProvider="{rectangles}" itemRenderer="RectangleRenderer" />
</s:Application>
```

Then, the `itemRenderer` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true" 
                click="whenClicked()" 
                x="{data.x}" y="{data.y}" 
                width="{data.width}" height="{data.height}">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            private function whenClicked():void {
                Alert.show("clicked");
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="{data.color}" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```